# Is there a way to identify codec of a streaming video?

Tags: video-streaming, twilio

We are using Twilio to stream video for a group of users and it does not work on safari. Considering safari supports H264, we want to be sure that the video is being streamed with H264. So, is there a way to identify the codec of the video being streamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check in chrome by loading the stream and checking `chrome://media-internals`
Otherwise you must find the endpoint that contains the actual media.

Comment: What do you mean 'fiind the endpoint'?  My device has to know the codec being used, is there really no way to get that information from the SDK?

Comment: It is being replaced by Media tab in chrome dev tools.